# Deriving Unit cost function

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, international-trade

Unit cost function is the minimum cost to produce **one unit** of output.

[image]

The solution to the above problem is:

[image]

where ai(w,r) is the amount of labour needed to produce 1 unit of good i at factor prices (w,r).

How do we arrive at this specific solution by finding the optimal values of K and L?

Answer (score 0):

Here $a_{iL}(w,r)$ and $a_{iK}(w,r)$ is just notation for the solutions to the cost minimization problem. There is no need for any derivation. It could only be possible to find a specific solution (i.e. solve the cost minimization problem to find the functions $a_{iL}$ and $a_{iK}$) if you were given a specific production function $f_i$.

[I suppose here $f_i$ must be constant returns to scale to make the idea of a unit cost function useful.]